# how to implement n^2 (n squared) recursively?

Tags: c++, recursion

Is there a way in a function in C++ to call an integer into a function, which that function will calculate the n<sup>2</sup> of that number recursively?

Comment: If you mean the square of `n` then you should say so. The question is tagged `c++` and [`n^2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Bitwise_arithmetic_operators) means something else in C++.

Comment: `n` to the 2nd power is simply `n*n`, why would you want to calculate that recursively?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Probably trying to learn some concepts and implementations of recursion.

Answer (score 4):

`n^2` doesn't need a function. It's just `n*n`. If you are looking for a general exponentiation function like `x^y`, the following is what you are looking for:

```cpp
int64_t recursivePowInt( int32_t x, uint32_t y){
    if(!y) return 1;
    auto temp = recursivePowInt(x, y/2);
    if(y % 2 == 0) return temp * temp;
    return temp * temp * x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

n^2 is n*n. A way to implement it would be using the product function recursively, like:

```c
int product(int x, int y) 
{
    if (y != 0)
        return (x + product(x, y - 1)); 

    // if any of the two numbers is
    // zero return zero
    else
        return 0; 
} 

int main()
{
    int x=5; 
    cout << product(x, x); 
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to use a single operator:

```c
unsigned int square(unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0; // base case

    return square(n-1) + n + n - 1; // recursive case
}
```